# C# - DataTemplate Error

Tags: c#, windows-8, xamarin

I'm getting an error:

'Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

I'm trying to create a DataTemplate with several bindings in it. Here's the code that's been giving me that error:

```
var cell = new DataTemplate(() =>
{
   //Bindings in here
}
);
```

This is a Windows 8 Store app I'm trying to make. It was originally an app written using Xamarin, however since Xamarin doesn't support Windows 8, I've had to convert Xamarin code back to regular C#. This chunk of code does work fine on the Xamarin versions of this project but for some reason I keep getting that error when I try it in a regular C# Windows 8 Store App.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var _TextBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
_TextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("MyBinding"));

var cell = new DataTemplate()
           {
               VisualTree = _TextBlock
           };
```

Comment: I don't think I can use FrameworkElementFactory in a Windows 8 store app. It doesn't let me reference it.

Comment: It does not matter.It is for example. Important in it is how to use DataTemplate constructor

Comment: Oh so you mean I should do all my bindings outside of the data template and then just add them in the datatemplate later?

Comment: You are trying to set lamba expression as a parameter of the constructor of DataTemplate. Because it is not correct, you recevied a error.

Comment: Yes, You should do it outside.

Comment: I've done all the bindings outside, but I'm not sure what to add inside the DataTemplate. The DataTemplate needs to be used in a listView but right now the DataTemplate is empty after I moved everything out.